# Can't post dictionary with array with AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, afnetworking

Apparently, the server can't understand my dictionary with array.
I wrote this

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://"];
self.manager = [[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

self.manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];

AFJSONResponseSerializer *responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];
[self.manager setResponseSerializer:responseSerializer];
self.manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [self.manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes setByAddingObject:@"text/html"];

NSDictionary *parameters = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                            [SOUser sharedManager].id, @"id",
                            @"vk", @"socialId",
                            [SOUser sharedManager].firstName, @"firstName",
                            [SOUser sharedManager].lastName, @"lastName",
                            [SOUser sharedManager].sex, @"gender",
                            [SOUser sharedManager].friends, @"friends", nil];

[self.manager POST:@"api/user/"
   parameters:parameters
      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
          //NSLog(@"Response: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
          NSLog(@"OPERATION = %@", operation);
          NSLog(@"%@", operation.responseString);
          NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
          NSLog(@"Token = %@", [responseObject objectForKey:@"token"]);
          [SOUser sharedManager].legendaryToken = [responseObject objectForKey:@"token"];
      } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
          NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
          NSLog(@"message: %@", [operation.responseObject objectForKey:@"message"]);
          NSLog(@"operation: %@", [operation.responseObject objectForKey:@"errors"]);
          NSDictionary *ac = [operation.responseObject objectForKey:@"errors"];
          NSLog(@"%@", [ac objectForKey:@"email"]);
          NSString *fg = [ac objectForKey:@"email"];
          NSLog(@"%@", fg);
      }];
```

Where `[SOUser sharedManager].friends` is `NSMutableArray`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
    [self.friends addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", i]];
}
```

And on server i receive all my data but instead of my array with my numbers server print string "array"? What it can be?

My JSON :

```
JSON: {
    email = "<null>";
    "fb_friends" = "<null>";
    "fb_id" = "<null>";
    firstName = Sergey;
    gender = 2;
    id = 17;
    lastName = Oleynich;
    phone = "<null>";
    token = 6990b71a61411d9d038dad1e2a54dd9f;
    "vk_friends" =     (
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7,
        8,
        9,
        10,
        11,
        12,
        13,
        14,
        15,
        16,
        17,
        18,
        19,
        20,
        21,
        22,
        23,
        24
    );
    "vk_id" = 3;
```

server

```
JSON : Id:17
vk_id:3
fb_id:NULL
firstName:Sergey
lastName:Oleynich
gender:2
email:NULL
vk_friends:Array
```

Comment: 1. It's semantics, but what you describe as your "JSON" is not really the JSON. It is what you get when you NSLog the object from which the JSON will be created. 2. You show us what the server received, but you don't show us now you generated that output. If anything, the fact that `vk_friends` is an `Array` is encouraging. I wonder if the problem is how you're examining/displaying the request on the server rather than a problem with the request itself. Show us how you generated that final "server" output.

Comment: @Rob 
Show us how you generated that final "server" output. I don't understand what i should show? Do you mean what exactly I send to server? How I can show it?

Comment: No, my question is how you output that last block of output at the end of your original question. If I understand correctly, you're asking "why do I see 'Array' for my 'vk_friends' key?" Well, we have to see how you generated that output. Your original question implies that you think the problem rests in the original request and I'm suggesting that the request might be fine, but rather it might just be a matter of how you are outputing `vk_friends`, something I can't answer until you show us how you created that final "server" output.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your request might be fine, but that the problem may simply be the manner in which you are displaying the "server" values at the end of your question. For example, if your server was written in PHP and you `echo` the variable that holds the array of `vk_friends`, it would simply display "Array".

If you want to display the array in PHP, you'd do something like:

```
foreach ($vk_friends as $vk_friend) {
    echo $vk_friend . "\r\n";
}
```

Frankly, if your server was responding to the app, you'd probably use `json_encode`, anyway, and this point is moot. But this might be why you are currently seeing "Array" in your output.

Comment: I make client. Server make another people and they say that on server they saw only array. That's why i thought that maybe my post was incorrect. Please can you give me advice how can I saw my original output information (in json) using NSLog in my code.

Comment: Your client request looks OK to me, but the real test is to watch the request in a tool like [Charles](http://charlesproxy.com) and look at the JSON that was sent when you run the app on the simulator. I bet you see the list of friends there. If so, share the JSON with your server friends and see what they say. If no, though, update your question with that JSON. The question is whether the JSON is valid or not or whether there is some innocent miscommunication b/w you and the server team.